# Image width and height in ASP.NET MVC 3 view

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a built in function to get the width and height of an image inside ASP.NET MVC 3 razor view? Should I use System.Drawing? Or must I delegate to jquery?

Comment: http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/using-mvc3-razor-helpers-and-jcrop-to-upload-and-crop-images/

Comment: @rahularyansharma I don't need to upload image, I just want to get the image size to plan the location of some divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image.FromStream(stream,true,false) will parse the image headers without loading the whole image... takes < 1ms for CPU time, although I/O time may be unacceptable (0-8000ms). If you do this from code-behind, you really should cache the image size data or you will get unacceptable performance under load. You *MUST* dispose the image afterwards, followed by the stream.

It may be better to put your div sizing logic in the client - much less overhead and much more scalable. jQuery is good at it :)

Or, alternatively, [just resize the image to the size you want](http://imageresizing.net) using image.jpg?width=300&heght=200.

Comment: OK so no built in support in view. I chose the jquery path.